# How to extract numbers from text in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have following pattern of string in Excel

```
 Salary
 Rs 4.5 Lakhs
 Rs 8.2 Lakhs
 Rs 2.5 Lakhs
 Rs 3 Lakhs
```

I want to extract numbers from above string

```
 Salary          New Salary
 Rs 4.5 Lakhs    4.5
 Rs 8.2 Lakhs    8.2 
 Rs 2.5 Lakhs    2.5 
 Rs 3 Lakhs      3
```

What formula I can use to extract numbers from the string?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you also look in here for similar questions? Have you looked into `MID` & `SEARCH` or `FILTERXML` to split by delimiter

Comment: I have tried `MID(K2,FIND(" ", K2)+1,256)` but this is extracting `4.5 Lakhs` not `4.5`

Comment: @Neil please refer the answer i have posted, that should serve the purpose, however there other ways to solve it,

Comment: As mentioned by @P.b you can use `FILTERXML` in this way `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0]")`

Comment: For more on `FILTERXML` you may refer the whole explanation by @JvDV Sir --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml

Answer (score 1):

You may try a formula like this using `SUBSTITUTE` & `REPLACE` function

Formula used in cell B2

```
=--REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A2," Lakhs",""),1,3,"")
```

And Fill Down!

[image: SOLUTION]